# Cefsharp get coordinate from html button

Tags: c#

Find the coordinates of an html element to execute a code click with CefSharp

From an html page I would like to find the coordinates of an html element and then execute a code click with Cefsharp.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I managed to click on the code buttons, but I have no idea how to do the rest and if it can be done.

For click:
chromiumWebBrowser1.GetBrowser().GetHost()
                .SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 1, CefEventFlags.None);

Comment: Any ideas for me?